# I am having an issue with my index.cshtml file it does not recognise the @model and the viewbag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

Guys I have tried everything 
1.uninstalled asp.net.mvc re-installed the same
2.updated my web.config file under the views folder to version 5.0.0.0.

3.tried all solutions here not able to get rid of the red mark under the @model in the index file and the viewbag
4.Copied a new web.config file from a new solution still no luck.
Please help!!!
5.I get a null reference exception when I try to run it not sure how to get past this.I am using VS2015 with razor views
This is my index.cshtml

```
 @model List<Shop.Models.Album>
   @{
       ViewBag.Title = "ASP.NET MVC Music Store";
    }
   <div id="promotion">
   </div>

   <h3><em>Fresh</em> off the grill</h3>

    <ul id="album-list">
     @foreach (var album in Model)
     {
        <li><a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Store",
                new { id = album.AlbumId })">

            <img alt="@album.Title" src="@album.AlbumArtUrl" />
            <span>@album.Title</span> </a>
        </li>
     }
     </ul>
```

And this is my web.config file under the views folder

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
            <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
            <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>

    <system.web.webPages.razor>
        <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
            <namespaces>
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
            </namespaces>
        </pages>
    </system.web.webPages.razor>

    <appSettings>
      <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0"/>
        <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    </appSettings>

    <system.web>
        <httpHandlers>
            <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
        </httpHandlers>

        <!--
                Enabling request validation in view pages would cause validation to occur
                after the input has already been processed by the controller. By default
                 MVC performs request validation before a controller processes the input.
                To change this behavior apply the ValidateInputAttribute to a
                controller or action.
        -->
        <pages
                validateRequest="false"
                pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
                pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
                userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
            <controls>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
            </controls>
        </pages>
    </system.web>

    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

        <handlers>
            <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
            <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Not sure what I need to do to get the red marks off my index folder?

Ok this is my controller code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Shop.Models;

namespace Shop.Controllers
{
    public class StoreController : Controller
    {
        MusicStoreEntities storeDB = new MusicStoreEntities();

        //
        // GET: /Store/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var genres = storeDB.Genres.ToList();

            return View(genres);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Store/Browse?genre=Disco

        public ActionResult Browse(string genre)
        {
            // Retrieve Genre and its Associated Albums from database
            var genreModel = storeDB.Genres.Include("Albums")
                .Single(g => g.Name == genre);

            return View(genreModel);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Store/Details/5

        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            var album = storeDB.Albums.Find(id);

            return View(album);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Store/GenreMenu

        [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult GenreMenu()
        {
            var genres = storeDB.Genres.ToList();

            return PartialView(genres);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Show me your controller

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem now.I just uninstalled the system.web.helpers package through nuget and reinstalled it and the red mark is gone working on a different problem now